# vlc does not save my settings

Tags: vlc

I wanted to install [TracktForVLC](https://github.com/XaF/TraktForVLC) to track my movies and tv shows automatically. But I am having a trouble setting up vlc on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Like mentioned in [Configuration](https://github.com/XaF/TraktForVLC#configuration), I went to Tools, Preferences, Interfaces and Main Interface. When I check **Remote Control Interface**, oldrc is set as initial value. I replace oldrc with rc and click save. When I check preferences again, **Remote Control Interface** is not checked and input form is blank.
So I left it on oldrc, which stays there. Then I want to save RC settings **TCP command input** insert *localhost:4222* and hit save. Again, when I reopen preferences, input form where I wrote *localhost:4222* is blank. Any idea why my settings is not stored?
I am using 2.1.6 vlc version. I enabled log to syslog but no log is written.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the program can't write to it's own config file.

I had the same problem in Windows, I ran VLC as admin then it worked. For Ubuntu, try doing the same thing by entering `sudo vlc` at the command line.

Might do the trick.

Comment: I am not sure this works (well it does not for me) but since I am not trying to make it work anymore I mark your answer accepted. Thanks

Comment: All good, please let me know if you endeavor on this again.