# VLC does not save my settings for TracktForVLC

Tags: vlc, streaming

I wanted to install [TracktForVLC](https://github.com/XaF/TraktForVLC) to track my movies and tv shows automatically. But I am having a trouble setting up vlc on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Like mentioned in [Configuration](https://github.com/XaF/TraktForVLC#configuration), I went to Tools, Preferences, Interfaces and Main Interface. When I check **Remote Control Interface**, oldrc is set as initial value. I replace oldrc with rc and click save. When I check preferences again, **Remote Control Interface** is not checked and input form is blank.
So I left it on oldrc, which stays there. Then I want to save RC settings **TCP command input** insert localhost:4222 and hit save. Again, when I reopen preferences, input form where I wrote localhost:4222 is blank. Any idea why my settings is not stored?

According to one of the answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/689100/598439), I tried running sudo vlc gives me the below response:

> VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry. If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports you can use vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and cannot be run by non-trusted users first).

Any other help answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer in [unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199422), changing VLC binary will allow you run vlc as root :

```
sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc
```

However run in root is a bad idea, as you should not use a root account for doing anything other than installing/user management.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. But as you can see, my objective is not to run as root. I am not able to save my settings in VLC. Running as root was a suggestion  in [another related question](http://askubuntu.com/a/689100/598439)
Is there anyway to achieve my objective?